# Why is a Google Map Icon affected by 'draggable' attribute?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that makes heavy use of mapping and uses custom icons.
These icons appear crisp and sharp when the marker is draggable, but when they are not draggable, the icon become blurry.

Not Draggable:

[image: Draggable:false marker]

Draggable:

[image: Draggable:true marker]

Does anyone know what the cause is, and more importantly how to prevent it from affecting the icon?

Comment: What you describe as "crisp and sharp" actually looks like worse rendering due to a lack of antialiasing. In case this rings any bells...

Comment: I didn't find any real solution to the problem. The only thing that made the image use the clearer version was to make it draggable.

In the circumstances where I don't want the markers to move, I simply return them to their original position on the dragend event.

Answer (score 2):

Markers by default will be drawn via canvas-elements(which may be the source of the issue).

When they are draggable they will be drawn via `<img/>`

You may force the rendering via `<img/>` by setting the `optimized`-option of the markers to `false`

Comment: I changed the optimized value to false but found it made no difference. Thanks for the input though.